# Performing a regex substitution Perl

Tags: regex, perl, substring, pcre

Assuming I have the IP `10.23.233.34` I would like to simply swap the `233` for `234`.  The first, second, and last octet are unknown.  The third octet is either `233` or `234`.  I want to do the substitution such that it matches the IP, subs, and keeps everything else while still switching the last octet.  For example:

Input: `10.23.233.34`

```
s/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){}233\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){}234\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/
```

Output: `10.23.234.34`

Comment: Duplicate, or rather subset, of the OP's complete question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239270

Comment: Aren't you switching the third octet? The last one is `34` and stays `34`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem really isn't suited well for a regex solution. Instead, I would do something like the following:

```
$in = "10.23.233.34";
@a = split /\./, $in;
if ($a[2] == '233') {
    $a[2] = '234';
}
print join(".", @a);
```

The above code is far more readable than any regex you might come up with. Furthermore, the next person who has to maintain your code will be able to actually read it.

Comment: That's fine assuming you don't have to validate that the string actually contains an IP address before modifying it.  Also, you have a typo - the condition on the if should have a `==`, not `=`.

Comment: The question states "Assuming I have the IP..." so I went with that assumption. Validating the input format is one more line if needed. (Thanks, fixed the `==`.)

Comment: I do have to validate it being an IP.  Lets say I have a line like "Hi My IP is 10.23.233.34.  I live .233 miles from new york city in building 10.233 subsection .233.34.  Ohh my friends IP is 10.33.233.55"  I both instances 10.23.233.34 should change to 10.23.234.34 and 10.33.233.55 should change to 10.33.234.55. Everything else should stay.  Ohh Greg what was wrong with posting about the upvotes?  It encourages answers.

Comment: Simple is always better. You can also use an embedded subroutine in your regex to increment your number (or apply whatever other logic you may need in the future) but this solution works and is more readable/miantainable.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes regexes make things brittle and harder to understand.  Nonetheless:

```
my $ip = '10.23.233.34';
...
for ($ip) {
    s!(?<=\.)233(?=\.\d+$)!234!;
}
```

**Details:** If given a well-formed dotted quad, the above looks for `'233'` in what must be the third octet:  preceded by a dot and followed by a dot, then one or more digits, then end-of-string.  The `?<=` and `?=` prevent anything other than the `'233'` from being captured, and then `'234'` is substituted.  This approach does *not* validate that the IP address is well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$byte = qr/(?:\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])/;
s/($byte)\.($byte)\.(23[34])\.($byte)/join '.', $1, $2, 467-$3, $4/e;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ip = '10.23.233.34';

$ip =~ s/(\d+)(\.\d+)$/($1 == 233 ? $1+1 : $1) . $2/e;

print $ip;
```

Output:

```
10.23.234.34
```