# Swap multiple parts of an IP using a Perl REGEX

Tags: regex, perl, replace, pcre

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performing a regex substitution Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238937/performing-a-regex-substitution-perl)

I have a line coming in via STDIN.  I need to swap part of an IP address while retaining the line.  IPs of the form XXX.XXX.233.XXX should change to XXX.XXX.234.XXX.  Everything else must stay.  For example the following line:

`Hi My IP is 10.23.233.34. I live .233 miles from new york city in building 10.233 subsection .233.34. Ohh my friends IP is 10.33.233.55`

should become

`Hi My IP is 10.23.234.34. I live .233 miles from new york city in building 10.233 subsection .233.34. Ohh my friends IP is 10.33.234.55`

I am not too good with Perl regex so maybe the Perl guys can chime in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\.233(\.\d{1,3})/$1.234$2/
```

Will do what you want in PCRE

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like it will work.  How can I pass the line in?  Assume the line is stored in the variable my $line.  my $line = "Hi My IP is 10.23.233.34. I live .233 miles from new york city in building 10.233 subsection .233.34. Ohh my friends IP is 10.33.233.55"

Comment: +1, but you forgot to add the `g` (global) flag.

Comment: $line =~ s/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\.233(\.\d{1,3})/$1.234$2/g

Comment: note that if you want to actually validate an IP you will need a more complex match than `\d{1-3}` probably something more like `(0?0?\d)|(0?\d\d)|(1\d\d)|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5])`

Comment: Or validate with https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Validate::IP